How to build a PyO3 extension with Yocto / OpenEmbedded?
I have a Python/Rust project that uses PyO3 to build a Python extension, written in Rust.
I have it set up with maturin and it works fine locally - it will build a wheel (.whl) and within that is my Python code and the Rust extension shared object, just as I'd expect.
I need to cross-compile this with Yocto (I'm stuck with Langdale, unfortunately), to put it in my embedded root filesystem, and I've quickly come to the realisation that I will need to ditch maturin for setuptools-rust, as there is no maturin support in Yocto Langdale at all.
So now my Rust/Python/PyO3 project is set up very much like the setuptools-rust example and I can build it locally, and the generated wheel contains what I'd expect.
Directory layout:
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
├── python
│   ├── my_project
│   │   └── my_module.py
│   └── tests 
│       └── test_my_module.py
└── src
    └── lib.rs

project.toml (partial):
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0.0", "setuptools-rust"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages]
find = { where = ["python"] }

[[tool.setuptools-rust.ext-modules]]
target = "my_project._lib"
path = "Cargo.toml"
binding = "PyO3"

(EDIT: removed setuptools-scm because Langdale version is < 8, use MANIFEST.in instead)
MANIFEST.in:
include Cargo.toml
recursive-include src *.rs

Cargo.toml (partial):
[lib]
name = "_lib"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]
pyo3 = "0.22.0"

Recipe python3-my-project.bb:
inherit externalsrc
EXTERNALSRC = "${TOPDIR}/../../my_project"

DEPENDS += " \
    python3-tomli-native \
    python3-setuptools-rust-native"

inherit python_setuptools_build_meta

EDIT: including python3-tomli-native fixed the error:
|   File "build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/my_package/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/picobuild/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
|     pyproject = tomllib.load(f)
| AttributeError: module 'tomli' has no attribute 'load'

This builds a .rpm but inspecting the contents shows no shared library present:
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project-0.1.0.dist-info/METADATA
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project-0.1.0.dist-info/RECORD
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project-0.1.0.dist-info/WHEEL
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project-0.1.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project/__pycache__/my_project.cpython-310.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project/my_project.py
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tests/__pycache__/test_my_project.cpython-310.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tests/test_my_project.py

(Not sure why this .whl contains the tests directory? Is that typical? Perhaps a quirk of the setuptools-rust directory layout.)
Looking in the bitbake log I can see that something called "picobuild" is used:
DEBUG: python3-my-project-1.0-r0 do_compile: Executing shell function do_compile
+ cd build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/python3-my-project/1.0-r0/python3-my-project-1.0
+ do_compile

+ export _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME=_sysconfigdata
+ _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME=_sysconfigdata
+ python_pep517_do_compile
+ nativepython3 -m picobuild --source /.../build/../../python/my_project --dest /.../build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/python3-my-project/1.0-r0/dist --wheel
...

Digging into this a bit, I see that the standard pypa/build front-end was replaced by "picobuild" around May 2022:
https://patchwork.yoctoproject.org/project/oe-core/cover/20220526171001.4074388-1-ross.burton@arm.com/
But a newer post in Jan 2023 seems to suggest that "picobuild" was changed back to "build" (a hint at a "migration"):
https://patchwork.yoctoproject.org/project/oe-core/patch/20230112112336.2254765-4-ross.burton@arm.com/#7902
Does anyone know the history of this? Is "picobuild" my problem here, in that it doesn't support the setuptools-rust plugin, somehow?

Inheriting from python_setuptools3_rust instead of python_setuptools_build_meta successfully builds and packages the Python parts of my project, but the Rust extension (I expected to see a .so or .pyd file) is completely absent. I think this is because python_setuptools3_rust is not using a PEP-517-compliant build step, and invoking setup.py bdist_wheel directly, which skips the Rust config in pyproject.toml.
At this point I've run out of documentation or examples to guide me.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.
It's a real shame I'm stuck with Yocto Langdale because the latest LTS, Scarthgap, does seem to have maturin support.

I've edited my original post as I was able to get my recipe to build with inherit python_setuptools_build_meta but the Rust extension is missing from the final package - I suspect something called "picobuild", but still investigating.

Hello, I have similar issue trying to cross compile https://pypi.org/project/rpds-py/ . Have you found any (alternative) solution?

@TocToc no, in the end I build my wheels outside of Yocto, and then just use a simple recipe to install them. It's clunky but it was the only solution I could find at the time. I'm still hopeful that Scarthgap will provide more options.
